# Установка Unity застывает

Tags: unity3d, установка

Как-то решил поставить себе Unity, но установщик застыл на этом положении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отменял установку (через закрытие процесса установщика). Установщик сообщил об ошибке и предложить "прервать", "повторить" или же "отменить". Я выбрал "повторить". Он удалил следы юнити и начал с нуля установку, потом прогрессбар опять застыл в этом же положении.

Что нужно сделать, чтоб продолжить установку или чтобы установщик не застывал/не зависал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ у [комьюнити юнити](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1135857/view.html): закрыть процесс с именем "Windows Host Module Installer". У меня установка продолжилась и успешно завершилась
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]